# Angular 2 table row component is rendered into the first column header

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have this html table in a pupil-list component:

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Selektiert</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Aktion</th>
      <th>Fächer</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let p of pupils; let i = index">
           <pupil-detail-display *ngIf="!isEditTemplate(p)"
      (selectedPupilUpdated)="onSelectedPupilUpdated($event)"
       [pupil]="p" ></pupil-detail-display>

    <pupil-detail-edit *ngIf="isEditTemplate(p)"
    (savedAddedPupil)="onSavedAddedPupil($event)"
    (savedEditedPupil)="onSavedEditedPupil($event)"
     (cancelledEditingPupil)="onCancelledEditingPupil()" [pupil]="p" ></pupil-detail-edit>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Both components pupil-detail display/edit contain each 5 td-tags.

These 5 td-tags are rendered **INTO** the **first th-tag** because of the comprising component which is also rendered as html element into the dom.

How would you fix such an actually common problem as the UI looks broken now?

**NOTE**

Consider that the components are dynamically switched at runtime. I can not remove that component as a wrapper...

Comment: Why -1 and close? Speak up guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with the table element, you *must* have a `td` element immidietly inside the `tr` element, otherwise the browser will try to fix this markup mistake by assuming the elements go outside the table body(in chrome at least), that's why you see it as a header.

My suggestion is to reorder your markup, combine your 2 inner components into one and use an attribute selector for that component.

ex:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of pupils; let i = index"
   pupil-detail
   (selectedPupilUpdated)="onSelectedPupilUpdated($event)"
   (savedAddedPupil)="onSavedAddedPupil($event)"
   (savedEditedPupil)="onSavedEditedPupil($event)"
   (cancelledEditingPupil)="onCancelledEditingPupil()" [pupil]="p"
</tr>
```

and this is some pseudo-code for pupil-detail-component:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[pupil-detail]',
    template: `<td *ngIf="edit"></td>.............<td></td>
})
class pupilDetail {
    constructor() {
    }
    *you code from both compnents*
}
```

Comment: sorry, but due to clarity I removed some code. It seems due to the missing code you provide a solution that makes no sense concerning the implementation, would you please re-read my post?

Comment: I had to take a few guesses, because I wanted to abstract out your implementation from the other components.

Comment: Yep, that's the route you need to take. However, there is no metadata property for `template` in `@Directive`, that needs to be a `@Component`.

Comment: Yeah, fixed it :)

Comment: Ok I see there is no better solution possible. I have the display/edit code all in one component thrown. Thats not component oriented... -no blame to you - If the ng-template would have a templateUrl + componentUrl it would work...

Comment: One component for a pupil seems more logical to me, if the pupil-detail is editable, it should just display additional GUI, but the entity is still the same.
Your original method suggested that display and edit are for different entities.(That's what I understand from your code)

Comment: Just think of having 20 tg-tags all with ngIf="edit"... and 20 ngIf="!editMode". I find that terrible. Hm... but i guess I could use this inside the new pupil-detail.component.html:         <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="getTemplate(pupil)" [ngOutletContext]="{ $implicit: p, index: i }"></ng-template> and switch the ng-templates based on a value inside the pupil-detail component, that would be better! I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the table markup is incorrect.

If `public-detail-display` and `public-detail-edit` are in fact table rows then you can merge them into a single component, mark it up as an `tr` element with an attribute-selector and utilize `*ngFor` variable `even` and `odd` to switch between which type of row (display or edit) that should be rendered.

Comment: sorry, but due to clarity I removed some code. It seems due to the missing code you provide a solution that makes no sense concerning the implementation, would you please re-read my post?

Comment: Not sure if you under stood my point. The problem is that the HTML markup is not valid and you need to adjust your Angular components to provide a valid output. My suggestion is to turn `public-detail-display` and `public-detail-edit` into `tr` elements. You can handle the 'switch' logic in the child component. Even with your edit I think this is what makes the most sense. Either way you will have to change your markup or code implementation to have it render correctly.

Comment: Not sure wether I understand you correctly, but it seems with your suggestion my typescript code for the edit and display component is within ONE component is that true? Then I can use my old approach with ng-template switching and all code in the pupil-list component. Thats very very bad.

Comment: Correct. See Omri Luzon's example above.